# Flutter Implement Custom Popup Ads

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, ads

I'm implementing a classified app using Flutter and Firebase.
I need to show custom popup ad (paid ad by seller) when user open the app or using the app.

Things to notice:

- One user can only see one ad by onnce (to avoid disturbance when using the app)
- Custom ad notification can include Seller Shop id, Item id and/or ad Image URL to show. So i can decide where to navigate the user.
- Once ad popup and once user tapped on the ad user will redirect to shop or sale item.
- User should not see same ad popup more than once but same other ads can popup hourly basis.

I can implement admin portal for sellars to create these promotional ads.
But my concern is, how can I send these ads to mobile side? And those ads should be automatically manage without any human interference.

Ex:

- Same ad cannot send to the same user again and again
- How long it will valid (Ad will expire within 2 days)
- Ad should be visible to all the active users

Can i use Firebase push notification for this kind of requirement? Or any other technology?

Please let me know. Your thoughts will be highly appreciate on this.
Thank you!

Comment: FCM is okay. But for in app popups, you can use In-App Messaging by Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging

Comment: Thank you very much @DarShan for the guidence. Seems Firebase In-App Messaging is a good candidate for this. I will definitely consider this.